# MVVM - fragment as a parameter to ViewModel's method

Tags: android, mvvm

I am building my own app in MVVM architecture and I've learnt that ViewModel should not have reference to view or the context, but how about a method's parameter in ViewModel which is Fragment? I have seen it several times in some MVVM projects (especially with Firebase Google SignIn) and I was wondering is it proper approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea, because:

1. Goes against the **MVVM** principle, `ViewModel` should not know about the `View`.
2. In android you have an another drawback if you're using the **Arch ViewModel** -> `ViewModels` will outlive the view in certain cases, like orientation-change. Thus having a reference to a view (`Fragment`/`Activity`) could cause a memory leak, since the GC can't free that view.